# Не создается исполняемый файл

Tags: g++

Ранее все было нормально, теперь перестал компилироваться.
Переустановил компилятор Mingw32 ничего не поменялось, проверил переменные среды тоже в порядке. Может какой то ключ в батник добавить чтобы показало где ошибка?

Win10, Mingw32, компилирую просто с батника по привычке, мне так удобней.
В батнике все просто:

```
g++ ts.cpp -o ts.exe
```

Comment: а какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: Так ничего и не пишет, просто батник выполняется и все.

Comment: Еще я заметил что если раньше батник исполнялся за 2 секунды примерно, то теперь 12-13 секунд думает прежде чем завершится.

Comment: Есть идеи у кого?

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. На другом форуме дали ответ.
Проблема в том что explorer почему то не запускаются bat файлы должным образом.
Теперь буду думать как это можно исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема крылась в  COMODO Firewall, а именно Авто-Containment.
Выключил эту виртуализацию в контейнерах и все заработало как раньше.